# Angular Unit Testing: Observable variable value not updating in the data service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I have a data service that is used by a component.

For example:

BookService:

```
...
private book: Book;
private bookSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Book>(this.book);
bookChanged = this.bookSubject.asObservable();
...
```

BookComponent:

```
...
book: Book;
ngOnInit() {
  this.bookService.bookChanged.subscribe(
    (book: Book) => this.book = book;
  )
}
...
```

Spec (test file) for the component:

```
describe('BookComponent', () => {
  let component: BookComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BookComponent>;
  let bookServiceStub: Partial<BookService>;

  bookServiceStub = {
    bookChanged: of({id: 123, name: 'Book 1'})
  };
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed
      .configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [BookComponent],
        providers: [
          {provide: BookService, useValue: bookServiceStub},
          ...
        ]
      })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BookComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should change the book with a new one', fakeAsync(() => {
    const newBook = {
      id: 769,
      name: 'Book 2'
    };
    bookServiceStub.bookChanged = of(newBook);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.book.id).toBe(newBook.id); // FAILS (still has old value)
      expect(component.book).toBe(newBook); // FAILS (still has old value)
    });
  }));
});
```

So the tests fail because the "book" variable does not update with the new values.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

NOTE: I actually wanted to test if the subscriptions in the component are working as expected or not!

REASON: I would like to check-in further tests that when the value in service is updated, does the DOM changes automatically or not

Comment: Also, I have tried adding tick(), but still no luck.

Comment: 'should change the book with a new one':  is this the test for the service or for the component? If you want to test the component (logic), you can set the book:  component.book = newBook;   fixture.detectChanges();

Comment: Good point @Marc!

But I actually wanted to test if the subscriptions in the component are working as expected or not!


REASON: I would like to check-in further tests that when the value in service is updated, does the DOM changes automatically or not

Comment: Sounds that this is a good candidate for an E2E test: testing component and service.

Comment: @Marc Maybe, but that would involve actual API calls which I want to avoid.

Also according to the Angular's testing docs: https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-observables.

This kind of things can be tested, I just want to know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the order of what happens:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BookComponent);

// The component is created now. So, its constructor is run and services instantiated.
// Also, ngOnInit is executed.

// ...

  it('should change the book with a new one', fakeAsync(() => {
    const newBook = {
      id: 769,
      name: 'Book 2'
    };

// And now you're overwriting bookServiceStub's bookChanged property.
// The problem is, the component doesn't care at this point, it already has a subscription,
// and it's attached to the original bookChanged stream.

    bookServiceStub.bookChanged = of(newBook);
```

If you don't have more tests to run in this suite (or if you don't need different contents of `bookChanged` in them), you can simply move `bookServiceStub.bookChanged = of(newBook)` earlier, before the component is created.

Comment: Thanks, but I have 2 tests, one with the original book (PASSES)
One with the updated book (FAILS, because the book never updates)!


Also, there is a subscription in the component, so it should update the book right?

Comment: Moreover, if I add a third random test, then I get the new value of the book in it. It's strange!

Comment: @PranavBhatia _Also, there is a subscription in the component, so it should update the book right?_ - incorrect. With this line `bookServiceStub.bookChanged = of(newBook)` you're overwriting the reference in the mock service, while the component has a subscription to the old object. And yes, explicitly running `ngOnInit` inside the test will also rerun this line `this.bookService.bookChanged.subscribe(//...`, which will (somewhat) fix the issue (now you have two subscriptions - the old one and the new one).

Comment: Thanks, I understand now!
However, is this a correct way to test or should I follow some other code style?

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while myself to figure out that [fixture.detectChanges();](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#detectchanges) actually was initiating the data binding of the component. Below should work still, by removing fixture.detectChanges(); from beforeEach() and putting it in each test, you are waiting to initiate any data binding to the component.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BookComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('should change the book with a new one', fakeAsync(() => {
    const newBook = {
      id: 769,
      name: 'Book 2'
    };
    bookServiceStub.bookChanged = of(newBook);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.book.id).toBe(newBook.id);
    expect(component.book).toBe(newBook);
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `component.ngOnInit();` makes my test run successfully.

```
it('should change the book with a new one', fakeAsync(() => {
    const newBook = {
      id: 769,
      name: 'Book 2'
    };
    bookServiceStub.bookChanged = of(newBook);
    component.ngOnInit(); // ADDED HERE
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.book.id).toBe(newBook.id);
    expect(component.book).toBe(newBook);
  }));
```

Is this a good practice though. or should I create a spy, etc. ?